# Security of unzipping user submitted files

Tags: php, wordpress, zip, unzip

Not so much of a coding problem here, but a general question relating to security.
I'm currently working on a project that allows user submitted content.
A key part of this content is the user uploads a Zip file.
The zip file should contain only mp3 files.

I then unzip those files to a directory on the server, so that we can stream the audio on the website for users to listen to.

My concern is that this opens us up for some potentially damaging zip files.
I've read about 'zipbombs' in the past, and obviously don't want a malicious zip file causing damage.

So, is there a safe way of doing this? 
Can i scan the zip file without unzipping it first, and if it contains anything other than MP3's delete it or flag a warning to the admin?

If it makes a difference i'm developing the site on Wordpress.
I currently use the built in upload features of wordpress to let the user upload the zip file to our server (i'm not sure if there's any form of security within wordpress already to scan the zip file?)

Comment: You can loop through files in file before extraction, yet you will need MP3 parser to determine if they are damaged or not. But for sure, you can choose which files to extract and which not.

Comment: Do not extract files into directory which can be browsed with browser. This will allow user to upload and execute some php script.

Comment: This comment in php.net may be useful: http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-entry-filesize.php#98949

Comment: @E_ERROR - The files will be unzipped to a temp directory and then immediately moved to a protected Amazon S3 bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code, only extract MP3s from zip, ignore everthing else

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = 'newzip.zip';

if ($zip->open($filename)!==TRUE) {
   exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}

for ($i=0; $i<$zip->numFiles;$i++) {
   $info = $zip->statIndex($i);
   $file = pathinfo($info['name']);
   if(strtolower($file['extension']) == "mp3") {
        file_put_contents(basename($info['name']), $zip->getFromIndex($i));
   }

}
$zip->close();
```

I would use use something like `id3_get_version` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.id3-get-version.php) to ensure the contents of the file is mp3 too

Comment: Not all MP3s have ID3 tags.

Comment: @TotalWipeOut - Thanks for the code... i'll give it a try over the next few days. 
I'm completely new to working with zip files in php - is it possible to remove any non-mp3 files from the archive?

Comment: Since you have to extract each file from the ZIP, just ignore them when you encounter them. Or, for maximum security (but less user-friendliness), bail and issue an error whenever you encounter non-MP3 data.

Comment: @BarryJarvis You can remove entries using `->deleteIndex($i)` method, in that loop, if you are keeping the zip files on the server.

Comment: @JayDansand My approach was ultra paranoid, dont decompress anything other than what you choose, but probably over the top. Might be a bit hasty to reject the zip because of a none mp3 file, as i can imagine playlists, coverart, Thumbs.db and other random files could make there way in these ZIPs by accident easily.

Comment: @TotalWipeOut If you're going to redistribute the ZIP, you'd absolutely want to remove any cruft. Or, someone could upload a ZIP with MP3s and virus.exe, and innocent users will be exposed when they download the ZIP.  That's why I'd selectively extract only MP3s, then build a new ZIP with those files - it'd ensure there are absolutely no zip bombs, comment overflows, or spurious files.

Comment: @TotalWipeOut - So you'd go with your original code, extract the MP3's, run some more checks to confirm they are actually MP3's (and not just renamed files) then re-zip the results?

Comment: @TotalWipeOut - Just playing around with your code now, and trying to understand it (again, i'm very new to php, so like to understand the code i'm using).
What is the difference/reason of using 'file_put_contents' rather than '$zip->extractTo' ?

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason they need to ZIP the MP3s? Unless there's a lot of text frames in the ID3v2 info in the MP3s, the file size will actually increase with the ZIP due to storage of the dictionary.

As far as I know, there isn't any way to scan a ZIP without actually parsing it. The data are opaque until you run each bit through the Huffman dictionary. And how would you determine what file is an MP3? By file extension? By frames? MP3 encoders have a loose standard (decoders have a more stringent spec) which makes it difficult to scan the file structure without false negatives.

Here are some ZIP security risks:

1. Comment data that causes buffer overflows.  Solution: remove comment data.
2. ZIPs that are small in compressed size but inflate to fill the filesystem (classic ZIP bomb). Solution: check inflated size before inflating; check dictionary to ensure it has many entries, and that the compressed data isn't all 1's.
3. Nested ZIPs (related to #2).  Solution: stop when an entry in the ZIP archive is itself ZIP data. You can determine this by checking for the central directory's marker, the number 0x02014b50 (hex, always little-endian in ZIP - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29#Structure).
4. Nested directory structures, intended to exceed the filesystem's limit and hang the deflating process.  Solution: don't unzip directories.

So, either do a lot of scrubbing and integrity checks, or at the very least use PHP to scan the archive; check each file for its MP3-ness (however you do that - extension and the presence of MP3 headers? You can't rely on them being at byte 0, though. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#File_structure) and deflated file size (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-entry-filesize.php).  Bail out if an inflated file is too big, or if there are any non-MP3s present.

Comment: They need to Zip the MP3's as we offer users the ability to download the individual mp3's or the entire album (zip file). Thanks for the links and comments - i'll read through them.

Comment: You could upload individual MP3s, then just tar/ZIP them on the fly when a user wishes to download the whole album, bypassing the ZIP issue. If you need to support ZIPs, doing an in-PHP extraction with some tests is the way to go; you can modify @TotalWipeOut's code to do the other sanity checks necessary: check inflated size of each file first, write out the stream in 8K chunks in a while() loop (instead of file_put_contents()) in order to scan for MP3-ness/oversize while writing, and stop/bail when you've written too much or the file finished without any MP3 frame markers.

Comment: Thanks once again.. i think i'll be doing some reading up on the Zip functions of PHP and also how best to handle the file checking.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code the file names inside a .zip archive:

```
$zip = zip_open('test.zip');

while($entry = zip_read($zip)) {
    $file_name = zip_entry_name($entry);
    $ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(strtoupper($ext) !== 'MP3') {
        notify_admin($file_name);
    }
}
```

Note that following code will only have look at the extension. Meaning that user can upload anything what has a MP3 extension. To really check if the file is an mp3 you'll have to unpack it. I would advice you to do that in a temporary directory.

After the file is unpacked you may analyze it using, for example ffmpeg or whatever. Having detailed data about bitrate, track lenght, etc will be interesting in any case.

If the analysis fails you can flag the file.